# file input null check erroring Object is possibly 'null' in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to check against input file being null in typescript.
the problem is that (if condition is erroring out) telling me Object is possibly 'null'.
how to check against null for this particular case ?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#image') as HTMLInputElement;

const loadImage = () =>{
if (input.files[0]['type']) {
    const fileType = input?.files![0]['type'];
   }
}
<input id="image" ref={inputRef} accept="image/*" type="file" onChange={loadImage} />
```

Comment: You should be able to do it by placing a ?  After the variable you expect to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the input element is *null* (or *undefined*) :

```js
if (input && input.files[0]['type']) {
    const fileType = input.files![0]['type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only want to return your JSX should there be an input to pass:

{
inputRef && <input ref={inputRef} {…code} />
}

Comment: run time error is after change happens to the input  , so this jsx solution won't fix the issue, plus ref.current.. and i want the input on display this will hide it and cannot even add file to it if the ref is false at start!

Comment: I thought that was the point!